# Auto adjust row height of AG Grid in angular when other columns are hidden/shown dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using AG-Grid version: ***21.2.1***
and I cannot upgrade my version due to some reasons.

I want to wrap cell content so that all content will be visible, which I achieve.
I have buttons to hide/show columns in the application.

The problem is when I hide the column, then the height of the row is not getting adjusted according to other columns.

How shall we active that grid will auto adjust to content if another column got hidden / show dynamically ?

I have simulated the problem in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-cn3def?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts,styles.scss).

Click on the remove button, and observe the height of the row persist rather than adjusting according to other column's content

Sample code from stackblitz

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  gridApi;
  gridColumnApi;
  defaultColDef = {
    width: 170,
    sortable: true,
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filter: true,
  };
  columnDefs = [
    {
      field: 'make',
      wrap: true,
      autoHeight: true,
      width: 300,
      minWidth: 300,
      hide: false,
      cellStyle: {
        wordBreak: 'break-all',
        whiteSpace: 'normal',
      },
    },
    { field: 'model', wrap: true, autoHeight: true },
    { field: 'price', wrap: true, autoHeight: true },
  ];

  rowData = [
    {
      make: 'Toyota ToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyotaToyota',
      model:
        'CelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelicaCelica',
      price: 35000,
    },
    {
      make: 'FordFordFordFordFordFordFordFordFordFordFordFord',
      model: 'Mondeo',
      price: 32000,
    },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
  ];
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }
  showColumn() {
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['make'], true);
  }
  hideColumn() {
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['make'], false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice and simple; on your show/hide, add `this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();`.

Edit: Add to this answer per acceptance from my comment.

AG-Grid isn't always very good when you're trying to tell it to do thing after thing after thing after thing. It doesn't seem to store up/batch commands to process, so it sometimes just... ignores you.

One thing I've done - which is very painful to do but has made it do everything I need it to - is to wrap various things in a simple timeout.

Gives AG time to do whatever it was doing and then move on to what I wanted it to do after.

```js
this.gridApi.doSomething();
setTimeout(() => { this.gridApi.resetRowHeights(); }, 500)
```

It's a little slow sometimes, bless it, give it some breathing room.

Comment: This worked in stackblitz .. thanks  :) , however in my actual integrated application, its not working at all  ... wondering any other property on grid which blocks grid to reset row height ?

Comment: I found sometimes that there's an issue with AG updating and handling too many things at once... does it perhaps work if you slap it in a 500ms timeout or something? I've had to litter my various things with timeouts because I'm trying to ask AG to do too many things at once (how dare I!).

Comment: tried with setTimeout as well .. .. no luck ...

Comment: yes indeed ag grid updating and handling too many things at once ... something some where ,some property denying to adjust rowHeight. Although , i should accept this as answer ,  but not working in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good luck with AG - it's nice, and fast, and does what it advertises... it's just a little painful to get there sometimes.